# 14.04 battery status is not working well

Tags: 14.04, battery

Problem : when I turn on my pc, the battery status is showing 95%. but it is still showing 95%, end of the battery. no more change.

I reinstall the power management from software centre. But it is still.

How could I solve it that

Answer (score 0):

Try in the console this command: `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`
It will give you a lot of informations about baterry, including the percentage, or you can download an app from the Software Center, or search to the internet for one.